# Why does summary() ignore NAs for the mean?

Tags: r

As most R enthusiasts are probably aware, `summary()` computes a mean of a data set even when NAs exist whereas `mean()` does not.

```r
 x <- c(1:10,NA)
 x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 NA
 mean(x)
[1] NA
 summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
   1.00    3.25    5.50    5.50    7.75   10.00       1
```

I think that the decision to not compute the mean if NAs exist is the better one, and I am wondering why `summary()` does. Beginners might draw the wrong conclusion from summary's results. It details the number of NAs, though. Shouldn't `summary()` behave as `mean()` does?

Comment: Maybe it defaults to `na.rm=TRUE`?

Comment: The answer is probably "because S did it this way".

Comment: Thanks, @NelsonGon. The documentation doesn't mention it, though.

Comment: @Roland, that could be a reason although I would still wonder why S behaved like that.

Comment: In the source code, a few steps reassign the `NA`s excluding them.

Comment: From `summary.default`: `else if (is.numeric(object)) {
        nas <- is.na(object)
        object <- object[!nas]`

Comment: @NelsonGon I understand how it is done but still I don't understand WHY the decision was made to let it behave that way :)

Comment: That's quite hard I guess, might be a design decision. Probably someone who has worked as part of the RC Team could answer that.

Comment: It's extremely unlikely anyone not involved in the decision can answer that. Accordingly, I've voted to close this question.